Optimizing Graph Expansion for Production Chain to Meet Target Output
I am working on a problem involving a directed graph that represents a basic production chain. Each node in the graph corresponds to an aggregate with a specific production capacity (in units per minute), and the edges represent conveyor belts with a certain throughput capacity (also in units per minute).
The challenge is to expand this graph optimally to achieve a target production rate at the final node. For example, if the basic chain can produce 5 units/min, but we need to produce 100 units/min, the goal is to determine the minimal number of aggregates (nodes) and connections (edges) required to meet this production demand.
I have been considering the concepts of graph homomorphism to explore whether the basic graph and a complete graph could be homomorphic. Additionally, I am interested in finding an expanded graph that includes the basic graph as a subgraph while satisfying the production requirements.
While researching potential methods, I came across the Ford-Fulkerson algorithm, the Edmonds-Karp algorithm, and Dinic's algorithm. However, I am uncertain whether these algorithms are suitable for solving combinatorial problems related to graph expansion, search, and optimization.
Are there other methods or approaches that might be more appropriate for tackling this problem?
